# determinar si una matriz de n elementos es palindrome(simetrica)

Tags: java, array, string

Saber si una matriz de n elementos es simétrica.
Una matriz es simétrica si se ve igual si está invertida.
Por ejemplo:
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a') es simétrica. ('Symmetric')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'a') no lo es. ('Asymmetric')

n será siempre un número par entre 2 y 10 (No se debe validar esto).

El programa debe imprimir Symmetric ó Asymmetric.

Código de ejemplo inicial:

```
static String[] myArray = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "c", "b", "a"};

static  int n=8;

public static void main (String args[]) {
   
}
```

Esta es una forma de realizarlo pero con un String normal:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cadena = "Programando en Java desde parzibyte.me";
        // Esta será la cadena invertida, primero está vacía
        String invertida = "";
        // Recorremos la original del final al inicio
        for (int indice = cadena.length() - 1; indice >= 0; indice--) {
            // Y vamos concatenando cada carácter a la nueva cadena
            invertida += cadena.charAt(indice);
        }
        System.out.println("Cadena original: " + cadena);
        System.out.println("Cadena invertida: " + invertida);

    }
```

Otra forma seria con pero tambien con un String normal, StringBuilder

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cadena = "Programando en Java desde parzibyte.me";
        // Crear un StringBuilder a partir de la cadena
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(cadena);
        // Y llamar al método reverse de StringBuilder (lo convertimos a cadena con toString)
        String invertida = stringBuilder.reverse().toString();
        System.out.println("Cadena original: " + cadena);
        System.out.println("Cadena invertida: " + invertida);

    }
}
```

Otra forma que encontre de realizar el ejercicio, pero tampoco me funciona para realizarlo con String[] Arreglo

```
public class Clase7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String entrada = scanner.nextLine();
        char[] caracteres = entrada.toCharArray();
        char[] volteado = new char[caracteres.length];
        int num = 0;
        for(int i = caracteres.length; i>0; i--){
            volteado[num] = caracteres[i-1];
            num++;
        }
        String volteado2 = new String(volteado);
        if(entrada.equalsIgnoreCase(volteado2)){
            System.out.println("Es palindromo");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No es palindromo");
        }
    }
    
}
```

No entiendo como realizar con el arreglo de string para voltearlo y luego compararlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que muestras en tus ejemplos son como saber si la cadena ingresada es `Palindromo`, lo que tú quieres es saber si es simetrico o asimetrico.
Ejemplo: si ingresas la cadena `abba` tendrías que comparar el primer elemento de la cadena con el elemento n de la cadena, luego tendrias que comparar el segundo elemento con el elemento n-1 y así sucesivamente; llevando esto a código tenemos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String entrada = scanner.nextLine();
        char[] caracteres = entrada.toCharArray();
        
        int n=caracteres.length;
        //variable booleano que cambia de valor si al comparar los elementos
        //no son iguales
        boolean simetrico=true;

        //recorremos el arreglo hasta la mitad 
        for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++){
            //comparamos el primero con el ultimo
            //el segundo con (n-1)
            //el tercero con (n-2) y asi sucesivamente
            
            if(caracteres[i]!=caracteres[(n-1)-i]){
            //(n-1) es porque los arreglos comienzan de 0 a n-1
                simetrico=false;
            }
        }
        //validamos el valor del booleano simetrico
        if(simetrico)System.out.println("Simetrico");
        else System.out.println("Asimetrico");
    }
```

Comment: gracias por tu explicación, voy a tratar de replicarlo con los datos de static String[] myArray = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "c", "b", "a"}; y a partir de aquí tener la respuesta.